# Kendoui- set color in chart dynamically

Tags: kendo-ui, dojo, telerik, kendo-chart

When we work with KendoUI, we need to specify the backcolor of the chart. like this:

```
{
      category: "Latin America",
      value: 16.3,
      color: "#068c35"
}
```

See the full code below or example [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/OtUmi). I want to know, instead of specifying the backcolor for each component, is it possible to set the base color and then kendoui will use variation of the base color and set the backcolor for remaining component.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/donut-charts/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart" style="background: center no-repeat url('../content/shared/styles/world-map.png');"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    position: "bottom",
                    text: "Share of Internet Population Growth"
                },
                legend: {
                    visible: false
                },
                chartArea: {
                    background: ""
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "donut",
                    startAngle: 150
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "2011",
                    data: [{
                        category: "Asia",
                        value: 30.8,
                        color: "#9de219"
                    },{
                        category: "Europe",
                        value: 21.1,
                        color: "#90cc38"
                    },{
                        category: "Latin America",
                        value: 16.3,
                        color: "#068c35"
                    },{
                        category: "Africa",
                        value: 17.6,
                        color: "#006634"
                    },{
                        category: "Middle East",
                        value: 9.2,
                        color: "#004d38"
                    },{
                        category: "North America",
                        value: 4.6,
                        color: "#033939"
                    }]
                }, {
                    name: "2012",
                    data: [{
                        category: "Asia",
                        value: 53.8,
                        color: "#9de219"
                    },{
                        category: "Europe",
                        value: 16.1,
                        color: "#90cc38"
                    },{
                        category: "Latin America",
                        value: 11.3,
                        color: "#068c35"
                    },{
                        category: "Africa",
                        value: 9.6,
                        color: "#006634"
                    },{
                        category: "Middle East",
                        value: 5.2,
                        color: "#004d38"
                    },{
                        category: "North America",
                        value: 3.6,
                        color: "#033939"
                    }],
                    labels: {
                        visible: true,
                        background: "transparent",
                        position: "outsideEnd",
                        template: "#= category #: \n #= value#%"
                    }
                }],
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= category # (#= series.name #): #= value #%"
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use js function and logic do there.

```
{
    category: "Africa",
    value: 17.6,
    color: GetColor
}
```

[example here](http://dojo.telerik.com/OtUmi/2)

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: it is close to what I want, but I am looking to specify only one base color. and based on that color, system should pick color for remaining component. Currently you have specified multiple colors (red, blue,green). Also it would be great if you could explain how this is working. voting up for helpful answer !!

Comment: Well, to how it works: There is array with color (indexes 0,1 and 2). Everytime it is called I perform modulo operation of 3 (so it will always return number in border of array) to return a value and increment variable. Color property in kendo can be specified in string as you have posted in question post. So function just returns color in string acceptable by kendo ... 
And to your base color functionality: I don't get how exactly do you mean it. Specifiy for example green and then generate less green and less green for each "part of pie"? Based on value or randomly?

Answer (score 2):

Based on @ademar's answer, I have updated the [solution](http://dojo.telerik.com/OtUmi/4)

this is how the `GetColor` function looks

```
 var color = "#2b577011";
      var percent = -20;
      function GetColor(val)
      {
            var R = parseInt(color.substring(1,3),16);
            var G = parseInt(color.substring(3,5),16);
            var B = parseInt(color.substring(5,7),16);

            R = parseInt(R * (100 + percent) / 100);
            G = parseInt(G * (100 + percent) / 100);
            B = parseInt(B * (100 + percent) / 100);

            R = (R<255)?R:255;  
            G = (G<255)?G:255;  
            B = (B<255)?B:255;  

            var RR = ((R.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+R.toString(16):R.toString(16));
            var GG = ((G.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+G.toString(16):G.toString(16));
            var BB = ((B.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+B.toString(16):B.toString(16));

            color = "#"+RR+GG+BB;
            return color;
      }
```

Here is full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/donut-charts/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart" style="background: center no-repeat url('../content/shared/styles/world-map.png');"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    position: "bottom",
                    text: "Share of Internet Population Growth"
                },
                legend: {
                    visible: false
                },
                chartArea: {
                    background: ""
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "donut",
                    startAngle: 150
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "2012",
                    data: [{
                        category: "Asia",
                        value: 53.8,
                        color: GetColor
                    },{
                        category: "Europe",
                        value: 16.1,
                        color: GetColor
                    },{
                        category: "Latin America",
                        value: 11.3,
                        color: GetColor
                    },{
                        category: "Africa",
                        value: 9.6,
                        color: GetColor
                    },{
                        category: "Middle East",
                        value: 5.2,
                        color:GetColor
                    },{
                        category: "North America",
                        value: 3.6,
                        color: GetColor
                    }],
                    labels: {
                        visible: true,
                        background: "transparent",
                        position: "outsideEnd",
                        template: "#= category #: \n #= value#%"
                    }
                }],
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= category # (#= series.name #): #= value #%"
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);

      var color = "#63C6FF";
      var percent = -20;
      function GetColor(val)
      {

            var R = parseInt(color.substring(1,3),16);
            var G = parseInt(color.substring(3,5),16);
            var B = parseInt(color.substring(5,7),16);

            R = parseInt(R * (100 + percent) / 100);
            G = parseInt(G * (100 + percent) / 100);
            B = parseInt(B * (100 + percent) / 100);

            R = (R<255)?R:255;  
            G = (G<255)?G:255;  
            B = (B<255)?B:255;  

            var RR = ((R.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+R.toString(16):R.toString(16));
            var GG = ((G.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+G.toString(16):G.toString(16));
            var BB = ((B.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+B.toString(16):B.toString(16));

            color = "#"+RR+GG+BB;
            return color;
      }
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code makes no sense to me - the `GetColor` method takes a parameter `val` which is inexplicably never used